# Using a while loop to compare and modify a Series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For each row of my dataframe, I would need to:

- get the last word from a coma-separated list;
- Check if this word is already the last word of an other list in the Series;
- If not: loop through the list from its end to get the first one that matches this condition.

I took a Series containing lists of random characters as an example

In order to update the 'Last' Column, I was trying to use a function containing a while loop, but I can't figure out how to get it done, What are best practices to achieve this?

```
In[5]:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'List': ['6,f,e,w,m,i,n', '7,m,2,n,3,k,i', 'h,e,a,l,5,v,8', 'c,t,i,v,t,n,1', 'o,q,k,2,p', '6,b,p,n,7,1,k', '3,u,v,q,e,1,z,w', 'm,h,o,b,8,6,n'
 ]})

In[6]:
df

Out[6]:
    List
0   6,f,e,w,m,i,n
1   7,m,2,n,3,k,i
2   h,e,a,l,5,v,8
3   c,t,i,v,t,n,1
4   o,q,k,2,p
5   6,b,p,n,7,1,k
6   3,u,v,q,e,1,z,w
7   m,h,o,b,8,6,n

In[14]:
df['Last'] = df['List'].str.split(',').str[-1]
df['List-length'] = df['List'].str.split(",").apply(len)
df['frequency'] = df.groupby('Last')['Last'].transform('count'
df 

Out[14]:
    List             Last   List-length  frequency
0   6,f,e,w,m,i,n     n         7          2
1   7,m,2,n,3,k,i     i         7          1
2   h,e,a,l,5,v,8     8         7          1
3   c,t,i,v,t,n,1     1         7          1
4   o,q,k,2,p         p         5          1
5   6,b,p,n,7,1,k     k         7          1
6   3,u,v,q,e,1,z,w   w         8          1
7   m,h,o,b,8,6,n     n         7          2

In[1]:
def avoid_singles(d):
    index = -2
    remaining_items = d['List-length']
    number_of_singles = d.loc[d['frequency'] == 1].size
    while number_of_singles >= 1:
        d['Last'] = np.where((df['frequency'] == 1) & (d['List-length'] >= abs(index)), d['List'].str.split(",").str[index], d['Last'])
        df['frequency'] = df.groupby('Last')['Last'].transform('count')
        number_of_singles = d.loc[d['frequency'] == 1].size
        index += -1

avoid_singles(df)
```

And the expected `Last` column:

```
Last
    0   n
    1   k
    2   h
    3   n
    4   k
    5   k
    6   3
    7   n
```

Comment: So you want to get the index of first occurence of the last word?

Comment: I edited my question with the expected 'Last' column, At row 0 "n" is already the last character of the list at row 7, so I keep it. However, at row 1, "i" is not the last character of any other row, so I check if the second to last character "k" meets this requirement. "k" being the last character at row 5, i can keep it... and so on

Comment: Can you reformat your data and code as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Parsing the data into Pandas rather than keeping it in `list` form will make it easier for you to operate on entire rows or columns.

Comment: @ralex, I hope my reformating will help. By "parsing data into pandas rather than keeping it in list", do you mean that I need to split the characters list in separate columns ? and make the comparison afterwards ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.apply` to go through the samples and then compute `np.equal.outer` for the characters with the last character of each other sample; `np.argwhere` let's you select the first character that matches this condition:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'List': ['6,f,e,w,m,i,n', '7,m,2,n,3,k,i', 'h,e,a,l,5,v,8', 'c,t,i,v,t,n,1', 'o,q,k,2,p', '6,b,p,n,7,1,k', '3,u,v,q,e,1,z,w', 'm,h,o,b,8,6,n']})

def get_char(row):
    l_reverse = row.l[::-1]
    mask = np.equal.outer(l_reverse, tmp.l.str[-1])
    mask[:, row.i] = False  # Do not match with same row.
    mask[-1, 0] = True  # Set any element in last row to True so we can fallback to the last character.
    return l_reverse[np.argwhere(mask)[0, 0]]  # Select the first matching character.

tmp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(
    l=df.List.str.split(','),
    i=np.arange(len(df))
))
df['Last'] = tmp.apply(get_char, axis=1)
```

Which outputs the following:

```
0    6,f,e,w,m,i,n    n
1    7,m,2,n,3,k,i    k
2    h,e,a,l,5,v,8    h
3    c,t,i,v,t,n,1    n
4        o,q,k,2,p    k
5    6,b,p,n,7,1,k    1
6  3,u,v,q,e,1,z,w    1
7    m,h,o,b,8,6,n    n
```

Note the samples 5, 6 output `1` and `1` respectively (as opposed to the example you provided) but this is the first character that matches the condition according to the rules you specified (`k` is not the last character in any other row but `1` is (sample 3)).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this numpy.equal.outer function which is really fast.

Answer (score 1):

An identical result to @a_guest but without dropping into numpy. Theirs looks more elegant to me and runs faster. If you want to re-use the data then keeping values in a DataFrame rather than lists might save you future effort.

```
In [0]: %timeit mine()
9.7 ms ± 295 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [1]: %timeit theirs()
5.97 ms ± 131 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```py
import pandas as pd

stringlist = ['6,f,e,w,m,i,n', '7,m,2,n,3,k,i', 'h,e,a,l,5,v,8', 'c,t,i,v,t,n,1',
              'o,q,k,2,p', '6,b,p,n,7,1,k', '3,u,v,q,e,1,z,w', 'm,h,o,b,8,6,n']

# Split strings into a nested list with the elements reversed
nested = [s.split(',')[::-1] for s in stringlist]
df = pd.DataFrame(nested)
# keep the first strings of each list as the fallback case
first_strings = pd.Series([s.split(',')[0] for s in stringlist])

def next_valid(x):
    """Remove NaN values and select the first remaining value. Return NaN
    if an IndexError is raised because no values remained after removing NaNs."""
    try:
        result = x.dropna(how='any').iat[0]
    except IndexError:
        result = pd.np.nan
    return result

# mask the last strings that don't appear in any other row
last_strings = df.loc[:, 0].where(df.loc[:, 0].duplicated(keep=False))
# mask string_i to string_i-1 that are not the last string of any row
not_last_strings = df.loc[:, 1:].where(df.loc[:, 1:].isin(df.loc[:, 0].unique()))
# in descending order, choose the next valid string...
# ...or, if no strings were the last string of another row, return NaN
nextbest = not_last_strings.apply(next_valid, axis=1)
# where the next best string is NaN, use the fallback value
substitutes = nextbest.where(nextbest.notnull(), first_strings)
# where last strings are unique, use the next best string
result = last_strings.where(last_strings.notnull(), substitutes)
```

```
In  [2]:  pd.DataFrame([last_strings, nextbest, first_strings, substitutes, result],
index=['last_strings', 'nextbest', 'first_strings', 'substitutes', 'result']).T
  last_strings nextbest first_strings substitutes result
0            n        i             6           i      n
1          NaN        k             7           k      k
2          NaN      NaN             h           h      h
3          NaN        n             c           n      n
4          NaN        k             o           k      k
5          NaN        1             6           1      1
6          NaN        1             3           1      1
7            n        8             m           8      n
```